# getting a search bar working using AJAX in ASP.net application

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, ajax

im trying to get a sech bar going for searching though a table and only displaying the results based off the title . the program does give me any errors or exceptions but when i press the search button nothing happens.
any help would be appreciated

the code inside my view

```
       <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    getFileSharingsAjax(0)
});
function searchFileSharings() {
    var searchQuery = $("#txtSearch").val();
    getFileSharingsAjax(searchQuery);
}
function filterMovies() {
    $("#txtSearch").val("");

    getFileSharingsAjax("");
}
function getFileSharingsAjax(searchQuery) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:"@Url.Action("GetFileSharingsAjax")",
        data: {

searchQuery: searchQuery
    }, success:function(ViewResult){
        $("#ajax-files").html(ViewResult);
}

});
}
</script>
```

my controller class

```
     public ActionResult GetFileSharingsAjax(string searchQuery)
    {
        var query = from m in db.FileShare
                    select m;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchQuery))
        {
            query = query.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchQuery));
        }

        return View("Files", query.ToList());
    }
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: What _it will not work_? Are you stil getting errors (_i have manged to remove all erroes and exceptions_)?

Comment: when i  try to perform the search, nothing happens.